# CSS: Combining static html class with dynamic class that uses attribute selector

Tags: css, attributes

Html :

```
<div class="main main-280">
```

"main-280" is dynamically generated and may change so css for that selector alone would be:

```
div[class^="main-"]{-------}
```

But how do I target both classes as in .main.main-280 using an attribute selector? It seems like this wouldn't work:

```
.main.div[class^="main-"]{-------}
```

Comment: Hi Matt, I put up an answer which suggested using these two selector combinations: div[class~="main"][class*=" main-"], div[class~="main"][class^="main-"] It seemed to work for me but the answer has been downvoted so I've removed it. I'd be interested in you trying out those two and tell me whether it helps or not as I can't see what's wrong with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I know what you exactly mean, but:

```js
const main = document.querySelector('.main');

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',  () => main.classList.toggle('main-280'));
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

div[class^="main"][att="alwaysVisible"] {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: royalblue;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.main.main-280 {
  box-shadow: 4px 8px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="main main-280" att="alwaysVisible"></div>
<button>toggle class main-280</button>
```

Comment: I have upvoted it as I think that it answers the question (as it can be understood)